# Dynamic queries and setting variables in Snowflake without using RESULT_SCAN

Tags: sql, dynamic, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**The problem**

I have an authorisation matrix table that shows which teams should have viewing access to which database objects. It looks something like this:

| dbObject | Team A | Team B | Team C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Contracts | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Users | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Invoices | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I want to build a stored procedure that loops over these records and grants/revokes the viewing rights. That way if the distribution ever changes or when I ever add more objects to our DWH I can simply run the stored procedure to fix the viewing rights.

**My solution**

I created two cursors. One cursor creates a list of dbObjects and one cursor creates a list of teams.

```
--creates a list with database objects / views
ObjectCursor CURSOR for
SELECT
    "dbObject"
FROM
    DB_COMMON_DEV.GENERIC.AUTORISATIE_MATRIX;
    
--creates a list with teams
TeamCursor CURSOR for
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    DB_COMMON_DEV.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'AUTORISATIE_MATRIX'
    AND COLUMN_NAME != 'dbObject';
```

I then use two nested For loops to build a dynamic query that checks the value for each dbObject + Team combination.

```
BEGIN 
    open ObjectCursor; --open the dbobject cursor
        FOR dbobject in ObjectCursor DO AuthoObject := dbobject."dbObject"; --assign the first value to AuthoObject
            open TeamCursor; --open the team cursor
                FOR team in TeamCursor DO AuthoTeam := team.COLUMN_NAME; --assign the first value to AuthoTeam
                
                    --use the values from the cursors to build a dynamic query
                    sqlQuery := 'select "' || :AuthoTeam || '" as Grants from db_common_dev.generic.autorisatie_matrix where "dbObject" = ' || '''' || :AuthoObject || '''';

                    --execute the query. It will return a 0 or a 1 based on if the team is allowed viewing rights on the dbobject. 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQuery;
                    
                    --put that 0 or 1 in variable sqlResult
                    sqlResult := (SELECT $1 FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())));
                    
                        IF (:sqlResult = 1) THEN
                        --grant select on view :AuthoObject to role :AuthoTeam; 
                        ELSE
                        --revoke select on view :AuthoObject from role :AuthoTeam;
                        END IF;
                END FOR;
            close TeamCursor;
        END FOR;
    close ObjectCursor;
END;
```

This code works (I tested it with pseudo code / log table inserts as a debugger). But I am new to Snowflake and I am not familiair with all the functions and the syntax.

I do not like the RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()) construction. It feels a bit 'hacky' but it was the only thing that worked to parse the result from the dynamic query into a variable.

Other options that I tried were RESULTSETS and other EXECUTE IMMEDIATE options.

Are there cleaner solutions for this specific problem?

Comment: I would look into snowflake scripting for this.   
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index